# Android Add-on site edit repository.xml

Tags: android

I have an Android Sdk Add-on that I want to publish on a site and make it possible to download via Android SDK and AVD Manager. 
Anyone who knows if there is a tool to generate the repository.xml file or do I have to edit it myself?

BR